# Change the color of the specific portion of a string wrapped in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

How to change the color of the specific portion of a string wrapped in a div:

We have a div like this:

```
<div id="text" class="text-class">Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers </div>
```

How we can change the color of the 'trusted online community' portion to red using the code template below?

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");

// We want to only change the color of this portion of the text
changeColor('trusted online community');


function changeColor(portion){

    // code to change the text color
    ...
    
    // function to animate the color from black to red
    function changeToRed(el) {
  el.classList.add("colorRed");
    }
    
};
```

```css
.colorRed {
    animation: colorRedAnime 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorRedAnime {
  from { color: #808080 }
  to   { color: #e80000 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<div id="text" class="text-class">Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap a `<span class="colorRed">` around the portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using replace():

You can just use the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to find and remove a specific portion of your string and use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to add the same portion back but with `<span>` tags around it.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

const changeColor=(a,b)=> a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(b, `<span>${b}</span>`);

changeColor(text,"trusted online community");
```

```css
span{color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="text" class="text-class">Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers </div>
```

### Using replace() with Regex:

If you want to replace multiple occurrences of a particular portion, you can use regex like this:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text');

const changeColor=(a,b)=> {
  let regexB = new RegExp(b,"g");
  a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(regexB, `<span>${b}</span>`);
}

changeColor(text,"trusted online community");
```

```css
span {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="text" class="text-class">Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers and Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers for a reason.</div>
```

### Using split() and join():

Another way to do this would be to simply split the string at each instance of a *specified separator string* which in your case is `trusted online community` using the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and then concatenate the string again with each other separated by a *specified separator string* which in your case is `<span>trusted online community</span>` using the [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method like this:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text');
const changeColor=(a,b)=> a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.split(b).join(`<span>${b}</span>`);
changeColor(text,"trusted online community");
```

```css
span {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="text" class="text-class">Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers.</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to create a `SPAN` and add it in the (inner)html

```
var lookFor = 'trusted online community';
var idx = text.innerHTML.indexOf(lookFor); //you could use regex also as an alternative
text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, idx) + '<span class="colorRed">' + lookFor + '</span>' + text.innerHTML.substring(idx + lookFor.length);
```